# Make custom node-red TCP function

Tags: javascript, node.js, iot, node-red

I'm working on a node-red v 0.10.40 and i'm trying to make a function which, whenever it receives a msg, opens a connection on a a remote host, sends the payload and then closes the connection. When i use the regular IO TCP node, it opens the connection right away and sits there, which is a behaviour i do not want.

I have tried to use some code i found on the internet but i need to require the 'net' module. I included it in the global context of settings.js on my hardware but i still can't use it. I get the following error message when i try to call new net.Socket() : "cannot read property 'socket' of undefined"

Please help, thank you

Comment: Please add the code to your post, don't worry to show broken code!

Comment: I assume you mean nodejs version v0.10.40 not the Node-RED version, as that would be incredibly old/out of date. But as @mch said, include the code, and the details of how you added the module to the global context

Comment: Here we go:
imgur.com/bDWIYCG 

I added net:require('net') to my functionGlobalContext on settings.js

The function contains the following code:

var net = context.global.net;
var client = new net.Socket();
client.connect(1337, '127.0.0.1', function() {
 console.log('Connected');
 client.write('Hello, server! Love, Client.'); // Send the msg
});

client.destroy(); // Close the connection

client.on('close', function() {
 console.log('Connection closed');
});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the "TCP Request" node is supposed to do this when you set a 0ms timeout. However it doesn't. Hopefully we fixed this with dave from the node-red slack team and it will be released soon. Cheers and thanks dave!